# Powering Arduino + raspberry pi 3 using one voltage source(Battery)

Tags: arduino

Hello I am making a simple car robot, which required a raspberry pi to be connected with Arduino using usb cable
My question is how to power them up using one voltage resource which is a    2 batteries (3.7v 9900mA  for each batterry)

Answer (score 1):

Connect your batteries in series and use a DC to DC Buck Converter to regulate the voltage to 5V.  You can then power both devices from the Buck Converter output or just simply let the Pi Power the Arduino using the USB to USB connection.  The DC to DC Buck converters can be purchased cheaply on Ebay or Amazon like this one:  [DCtoDC Buck Converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01KPRB8L2)

Answer (score 0):

Both devices can be powered through their USB ports.

Your question is not clear but I assume you want to power the Pi from 12 V and power the Arduino over USB from the Pi. In that case you need a 12 V micro USB power-supply capable of > 1 A.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffWPA5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. 12V USB PSU to feed Pi. Arduino powered from Pi.*

Comment: Where do you get the 12v assumption from?  There seems to be nothing in the question to support that.

Comment: Oops. I remembered the mention of "car" and forgot the 3.7 V so I wrote the answer for car battery supply. It's not clear whether the 3.7 V sources are series or parallel connected. I'll leave the answer as is until it's clarified.